# New VNet Naming Rules?

Tags: azure-virtual-network

We are using EV2 to deploy ARM template for creating VNets (e.g., vnet-prod-v0), and got below deployment failure today, which breaks our release pipelines:

Error: Code=InvalidResourceName; Message=Resource name  is invalid. The name can be up to 80 characters long. It must begin with a word character, and it must end with a word character or with '*'. The name may contain word characters or '.', '-', '*'.

This there a new VNet naming rule created? Because this rule is not listed in your documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/manage-virtual-network#create-a-virtual-network

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar issue when I edit my application gateway trust root cert `name` on the Azure portal. I also have edited Azure VNet name without any such error in the Azure portal. I don't believe the Azure Virtual network name has a new naming convention, see [naming rules and restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/naming-conventions#networking) about the network. Perhaps, the error message is coming from other resources' name instead of Azure Vnet name.